# Get row _ID of inserted row in database SQLite - Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am adding some values to a row in a database and I want to know how I can get the row _ID that was automatically generated. My code is as follows:

```
ContentValues session = new ContentValues();
        session.put(Database.Sessions.TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());
        session.put(Database.Sessions.MAP_ID, mMapId);
        session.put(Database.Sessions.SDK_VERSION, Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        session.put(Database.Sessions.MANUFACTURER, Build.MANUFACTURER);
        session.put(Database.Sessions.MODEL, Build.MODEL);
        getContentResolver().insert(DataProvider.SESSIONS_URI, session);
```

how do I get the row that it was inserted to?

Database class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    protected static final String DB_NAME = "LocalizationData.db";
    protected static final int DB_VERSION = 4;

    public static final String[] TABLES = { Maps.TABLE_NAME, Scale.TABLE_NAME,
            Readings.TABLE_NAME, Sessions.TABLE_NAME };
    private static final String[] SCHEMAS = { Maps.SCHEMA, Scale.SCHEMA,
            Readings.SCHEMA, Sessions.SCHEMA };

    public static class Maps {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Maps";
        public static final String ID = "_id";
        public static final String NAME = "name";
        public static final String DATE_ADDED = "date_added";
        public static final String DATA = "data";

        private static final String ID_COLUMN = ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT";
        private static final String NAME_COLUMN = NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL";
        private static final String DATE_ADDED_COLUMN = DATE_ADDED
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL";
        private static final String DATA_COLUMN = DATA + " TEXT NOT NULL";

        private static final String SCHEMA = generateSchema(TABLE_NAME,
                ID_COLUMN, NAME_COLUMN, DATE_ADDED_COLUMN, DATA_COLUMN);
    }

    public static class Scale {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Scale";
        public static final String ID = "_id";
        public static final String MAP_SCALE = "map_scale";

        private static final String ID_COLUMN = ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY";
        private static final String MAP_SCALE_COLUMN = MAP_SCALE + " FLOAT";
        private static final String ID_FOREIGN_COLUMN = generateForeignKeyColumn(
                ID, Maps.TABLE_NAME, Maps.ID);

        private static final String SCHEMA = generateSchema(TABLE_NAME,
                ID_COLUMN, MAP_SCALE_COLUMN, ID_FOREIGN_COLUMN);
    }

    public static class Readings {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Readings";
        public static final String ID = "_id";
        public static final String DATETIME = "datetime";
        public static final String MAP_X = "mapx";
        public static final String MAP_Y = "mapy";
        public static final String SIGNAL_STRENGTH = "rss";
        public static final String AP_NAME = "ap_name";
        public static final String MAC = "mac";
        public static final String MAP_ID = "map";
        public static final String SESSION_ID = "session";

        private static final String ID_COLUMN = ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT";
        private static final String DATETIME_COLUMN = DATETIME
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL";
        private static final String MAP_X_COLUMN = MAP_X + " FLOAT";
        private static final String MAP_Y_COLUMN = MAP_Y + " FLOAT";
        private static final String SIGNAL_STRENGTH_COLUMN = SIGNAL_STRENGTH
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL";
        private static final String AP_NAME_COLUMN = AP_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL";
        private static final String MAC_COLUMN = MAC + " TEXT NOT NULL";
        private static final String MAP_ID_COLUMN = MAP_ID
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL";
        private static final String SESSION_ID_COLUMN = SESSION_ID
                + " INTEGER";
        private static final String MAP_ID_FOREIGN_COLUMN = generateForeignKeyColumn(
                MAP_ID, Maps.TABLE_NAME, Maps.ID);

        private static final String SCHEMA = generateSchema(TABLE_NAME,
                ID_COLUMN, DATETIME_COLUMN, MAP_X_COLUMN, MAP_Y_COLUMN,
                SIGNAL_STRENGTH_COLUMN, AP_NAME_COLUMN, MAC_COLUMN,
                MAP_ID_COLUMN, SESSION_ID_COLUMN, MAP_ID_FOREIGN_COLUMN);
    }

    public static class Sessions {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Sessions";
        public static final String ID = "_id";
        public static final String TIME = "session_datetime";
        public static final String MAP_ID = "map_id";
        public static final String SDK_VERSION = "sdk";
        public static final String MANUFACTURER = "maker";
        public static final String MODEL = "model";

        private static final String ID_COLUMN = ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT";
        private static final String TIME_COLUMN = TIME + " INTEGER NOT NULL";
        private static final String SDK_VERSION_COLUMN = SDK_VERSION
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL";
        private static final String MANUFACTURER_COLUMN = MANUFACTURER
                + " TEXT NOT NULL";
        private static final String MODEL_COLUMN = MODEL + " TEXT NOT NULL";
        private static final String MAP_ID_COLUMN = MAP_ID
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL";
        private static final String MAP_ID_FOREIGN_COLUMN = generateForeignKeyColumn(
                MAP_ID, Maps.TABLE_NAME, Maps.ID);

        private static final String SCHEMA = generateSchema(TABLE_NAME,
                ID_COLUMN, TIME_COLUMN, SDK_VERSION_COLUMN,
                MANUFACTURER_COLUMN, MODEL_COLUMN, MAP_ID_COLUMN,
                MAP_ID_FOREIGN_COLUMN);
    }

    // ***********************************************************************

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.i("Database.onCreate", "*** Creating Tables ***");

        for (final String schema : SCHEMAS) {
            Log.d("Database.onCreate", "Command = " + schema);
            db.execSQL(schema);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.i("Database.onUpgrade", "Upgrading database from " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion);

        Log.w("Database.onUpgrade", "Dropping and recreating tables!");
        for (final String tableName : TABLES)
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    protected static String generateForeignKeyColumn(String fk,
            String refTable, String refColumn) {
        final String format = "FOREIGN KEY(%s) REFERENCES %s(%s)";
        return String.format(Locale.US, format, fk, refTable, refColumn);
    }

    protected static String generateSchema(String tableName,
            String... columnDefs) {
        final StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
        // Build beginning of CREATE statement
        ret.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ");
        ret.append(tableName);
        ret.append('(');

        // Build columns of table
        for (int i = 0; i < columnDefs.length - 1; i++) {
            ret.append(columnDefs[i]);
            ret.append(',');
        }
        if (columnDefs.length > 0)
            ret.append(columnDefs[columnDefs.length - 1]);

        // Build end
        ret.append(')');
        ret.append(';');
        return ret.toString();
    }

    public ArrayList<Cursor> getData(String Query){
        //get writable database
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns = new String[] { "mesage" };
        //an array list of cursor to save three cursors ec_1 has results from the query
        //other cursor stores error message if any errors are triggered
        ArrayList<Cursor> alc = new ArrayList<Cursor>(2);
        MatrixCursor Cursor2= new MatrixCursor(columns);
        alc.add(null);
        alc.add(null);


        try{
            String maxQuery = Query ;
            //execute the query results will be save in Cursor c
            Cursor c = sqlDB.rawQuery(maxQuery, null);


            //add value to cursor2
            Cursor2.addRow(new Object[] { "Success" });

            alc.set(1,Cursor2);
            if (null != c && c.getCount() > 0) {


                alc.set(0,c);
                c.moveToFirst();

                return alc ;
            }
            return alc;
        } catch(SQLException sqlEx){
            Log.d("printing exception", sqlEx.getMessage());
            //if any exceptions are triggered save the error message to cursor an return the arraylist
            Cursor2.addRow(new Object[] { ""+sqlEx.getMessage() });
            alc.set(1,Cursor2);
            return alc;
        } catch(Exception ex){

            Log.d("printing exception", ex.getMessage());

            //if any exceptions are triggered save the error message to cursor an return the arraylist
            Cursor2.addRow(new Object[] { ""+ex.getMessage() });
            alc.set(1,Cursor2);
            return alc;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Is this your own content resolver?

Answer (score -1):

You can easily select all rows from your table and then move to the last row.

Example:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

if (c.moveToLast()) {
    //c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Cursor c = db.query(
 Database.Sessions,                    // The table to query
 col_ID,                     // The columns to return
 null,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
 null,                                // The values for the WHERE clause
 null,                                // don't group the rows
 null,                                // don't filter by row groups
 null                                // The sort order
 );

if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{  long itemId = 
 cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.Sessions.Col_ID));
    }
else {
 //your databse has some problem as curser is pointing to null
      }
```